# Rotate array A K times; that is, each element of A will be shifted to the right K times

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, rotation, permutation

[Note: I am aware that there are solutions for this problem answered, but my question revolves around bug fixing for my code! ]

Hi, I have written some code to rotate an array A K times to the right. I have got a working solution for this, but I was wondering why this solution doesn't work.[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmsQG.png)

```
# The goal is to rotate array A K times; that is, each element of A will be shifted to the right K times.
def solution(A, K):
  At = A
  for i in range(len(A)):
    print(At)
    A[i] = At[(i-K) % len(At)]
  return A

A = [3, 8, 9, 7, 6]
K = 3
solution(A, K)

#[9, 7, 6, 3, 8]
```

This is the output

```
[3, 8, 9, 7, 6]
[9, 8, 9, 7, 6]
[9, 7, 9, 7, 6]
[9, 7, 6, 7, 6]
[9, 7, 6, 9, 6]
[9, 7, 6, 9, 7]
```

I'm not sure why `At` updates at each iteration.

Comment: Main point: Assignment never copies data.